# Can't link user_id to new created object - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails so any help would be much appreciated. I have the models userrs (recruiters) and adverts. Userr has_many adverts and Advert belongs to a user.

> Question: when a userr creates an advert i want the created advert to
>   be automatically linked to the userr that created the advert. I am
>   unsure how to go about this in the controller

i know how to assign an advert to a user in the console. but unsure how to do this in the controller

console

```
advert = Advert.first
advert.userr_id = 3
advert.save
```

route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :adverts

  resources :feedbacks

  devise_for :userrs
  devise_for :userjs
  root 'static_pages#homepg'
  get     'affiliate',    to: 'static_pages#affiliatepg'
  get     'terms',        to: 'static_pages#termpg'
  get     'privacy',      to: 'static_pages#privacypg'
  get     'contact',      to: 'static_pages#contactpg'
  get     'about',        to: 'static_pages#aboutpg'
  get     'recruiters',   to: 'static_pages#recruiterpg'
  get     'jobseekers',   to: 'static_pages#jobseekerpg'
  get     'approach',     to: 'static_pages#approachpg'
  get     'sector',       to: 'static_pages#sectorpg'
  get     'news',         to: 'static_pages#newspg'
  get     'offer',        to: 'static_pages#offerpg'
  get     'refferal',     to: 'static_pages#refferalpg'
end
```

i placed the below code:
in my advert controller under the create function:

```
def create
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.build(params[:advert])
    if @advert.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created advert'
      redirect_to recruiters_path
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

but i got the error:

> Couldn't find Userr without an ID

log - error message

```
Started GET "/adverts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-02 14:59:38 +0100
Processing by AdvertsController#new as HTML
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Userr without an ID):
  app/controllers/adverts_controller.rb:20:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (27.3ms)


Started GET "/adverts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-02 14:59:38 +0100
Processing by AdvertsController#new as HTML
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Userr without an ID):
  app/controllers/adverts_controller.rb:20:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/ARTLoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (26.2ms)
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150330233948) do

  create_table "adverts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "category_jobtype_id"
    t.integer  "category_positiontype_id"
    t.integer  "salarystart"
    t.integer  "salaryend"
    t.integer  "category_country_id"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "town"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.integer  "category_editorialapproval_id"
    t.integer  "category_applicationrequest_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "userr_id"
  end

  create_table "userrs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                    default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",       default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",            default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "companyname"
    t.integer  "category_businesstype_id"
  end

  add_index "userrs", ["email"], name: "index_userrs_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "userrs", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_userrs_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

model

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Userr < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :adverts
end
```

controller: Advert

```
class AdvertsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_advert, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @adverts = Advert.all
    respond_with(@adverts)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  # def new
  #   @advert = Advert.new
  #   respond_with(@advert)
  # end

  def new
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.build
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def edit
  end

  # def create
  #   @advert = Advert.new(advert_params)
  #   @advert.save
  #   respond_with(@advert)
  # end

  def create
    @userr = Userr.find(params[:userr_id])
    @advert = @userr.adverts.build(params[:advert])
    if @advert.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created advert'
      redirect_to recruiters_path
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @advert.update(advert_params)
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def destroy
    @advert.destroy
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  private
    def set_advert
      @advert = Advert.find(params[:id])
    end

    def advert_params
      params.require(:advert).permit(:title, :content, :category_jobtype_id, :category_positiontype_id, :salarystart, :salaryend, :category_country_id, :city, :town, :postcode, :category_editorialapproval_id, :category_applicationrequest_id)
    end
end
```

form for advert

```
<%= simple_form_for(@advert) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= f.association :category_jobtype, collection: CategoryJobtype.all, prompt: "select a category" %>
    <%= f.association :category_positiontype, collection: CategoryPositiontype.all, prompt: "select a category" %>
    <%= f.input :salarystart %>
    <%= f.input :salaryend %>
    <%= f.association :category_country, collection: CategoryCountry.all, prompt: "select a category" %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :town %>
    <%= f.input :postcode %>
    <%= f.association :category_editorialapproval, as: :radio_buttons %>
    <%= f.association :category_applicationrequest, as: :radio_buttons %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you please show the form you are using to create the Advert?

Comment: Yourr spelling of Userr with two r's is hurrting my brrain.

Comment: post the routes file

Comment: please post the error logs

Comment: apologies if the name of my model hurts. Userr is User recruiter i.e.: User-r and Userj is User jobseeker i.e.: User-j. I have posted up my routes & log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add `userr_id` to params:

```
 def advert_params
    params.require(:advert).permit(:userr_id, :title, :content, :category_jobtype_id, :category_positiontype_id, :salarystart, :salaryend, :category_country_id, :city, :town, :postcode, :category_editorialapproval_id, :category_applicationrequest_id)
 end
```

Second, add `userr_id` to the form:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@advert) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field(:userr_id) %>
```

Third, change the param name in `create`:

```
 def create
     @userr = Userr.find(params[:advert][:userr_id])
```

You can do the same via [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), without altering the form. It's much cleaner but needs more source changes. I can't give you the full syntax here, but it will look like the following:

```
#routes.rb
resources :userrs do
    resources :addverts
end
```

And the advert's form will become /userrs/[user-id]/adverts, so you'll be able to get the user id from the url instead of the form field. But you'll need to change all the path shortcuts.

Comment: thank you @oleg, very helpful, had no idea i had to make many adjustments - i assumed changes in the controller for advert alone was enough....but thanks....i do get an error but your guide is definitely good enough and understandable to help me through the errors to completely resolve it.

Comment: @ARTLoe maybe I missed something, plaese leave details in a comment. The main point is that AdvertsController doesn't know anything about :userr_id unless you pass it through form and params.